# Different return type based on boolean argument

Tags: typescript

I know there are a few similar-looking questions, but I haven't seen a solution there.

```
type ID = string
type MaybeID = ID | null

const defaultBranchId: ID = "1"
const currentBranchId: MaybeID = null

export function useBranchFilter1(withDefaultBranch = true) {
  if (currentBranchId === null && withDefaultBranch === true) {
    return defaultBranchId
  }
  return currentBranchId
} // <-- infers to MaybeID return type
```

I am expecting to always get `ID` return type.

Here is [the playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIlAvFAzsATgSwHYHMCwAUKJFALICGIARhPErAgD5TYCuANh0UQMYD22NFAAmEAGYVOwAELoK2XgAsYIgFyMGAIgCMWvoOG826dBGyz5ilevJVa9ZOy49CEAB5h+6YFHFtFYExBKDYUCDkFZQAxTA5gCHQdAAoAd0xgJTgJKXjI6wYMNggASigAbyIoKExxKGTjU3NLKJskRCdODigAMh6odMzsyWl85XbkItKKquqoM2ATbFEc0atlVVmAX1mFpahGswsxmyItqAB6C5rscUSUKGB+Oxo6BD30ZZIIVw8vHz8AV4QRCYQi6yUsXiiQATGkMllVnkIYV0MUShp6JVCNVavVDs0TqoJqwur1+oNESNka0SVMyti5vMIItPitqS1rJscVAdjyPssCccIdy+UQ-t5fP5AsFlmCTlCEugAMwAHgAKlAPAlsCIHtR+PwOBAFAA+eFDJGc5QaTWTNGlW1a9w6vWPB1QAD8mg0lFe9BmPLxDRMR2tbQ6nS45IGCOGuXDdIdDNm1QF7ITRJE212LP2QvDoqAA) with a few attempts I've tried - unsuccessfully.

Feels like a simple thing, but I am expecting it can't work like that since it's based on runtime value.

Comment: The language is inferring the correct type and indicating that 
you have a logic error. If `currentBranchId === null` but `withDefaultBranch === false` then `null` will be returned.

Comment: You can't always get an ID return type because you've specified one of the return types as a `MaybeID` type (`currentBrandId`).

Comment: Why are you expecting to get a non-nullable return type by returning a nullable value?

Comment: maybe you want to use `or`? `currentBranchId === null || withDefaultBranch === true`. Then it does what you want

Comment: @PierreDuc That would fix the type, but incorrect logic as it would always use default no matter if current has a value.

Comment: @FredyC right, but like Aluan Haddad already mentioned, because of the `withDefaultBranch` in the condition, the `currentBranchId ` can still be `null` when returned. Like i proposed, it will only return the defaultBranch if `withDefaultBranch` is set to true. If you put it to false, it will not return it (only when there is no `currentBranchId`. 

So the only way to fix it, is to change your logic, and it's hard to see what your logic is :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type is correct. There are two return types, one is `string` the other `null` which fits the type `MaybeID` since `type ID = string`.

Comment: I suppose you are right. Haven't realized there is actually the path when arg = false and then it can really return MaybeID. Oh well.